# not such file or directory libiptc.so.0

Tags: linux, debian

I have linux - debian wheezy

```
PRETTY_NAME="Debian GNU/Linux 7 (wheezy)"
NAME="Debian GNU/Linux"
VERSION_ID="7"
VERSION="7 (wheezy)"
ID=debian
ANSI_COLOR="1;31"
HOME_URL="http://www.debian.org/"
SUPPORT_URL="http://www.debian.org/support/"
BUG_REPORT_URL="http://bugs.debian.org/"
cat: file.: No such file or directory
```

I try run command sudo apt-get upgrade but I get message

> Reading package lists... Done
>       Building dependency tree
>       Reading state information... Done
>       The following packages have been kept back:
>         linux-image-amd64 oracle-java7-bin oracle-java7-jdk oracle-java7-jre postgresql python-reportbug reportbug
>       0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 7 not upgraded.
>       1 not fully installed or removed.
>       After this operation, 0 B of additional disk space will be used.
>       Do you want to continue [Y/n]? y
>       Setting up collectd (5.1.0-3+deb7u3) ...
>       [....] Restarting statistics collection and monitoring daemon: collectd/usr/sbin/collectd: error while loading shared libraries:
>   libiptc.so.0: cannot open shared object file: No such file or
>   directory
>       [FAILrestarting, configuration error failed!
>       invoke-rc.d: initscript collectd, action "restart" failed.
>       dpkg: error processing collectd (--configure):
>        subprocess installed post-installation script returned error exit status 1
>       Errors were encountered while processing:
>        collectd
>       E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)

Thank you for help.

Comment: Wheezy and Jessie : `/lib/libiptc.so.0` is provided by the package `iptables`. Debian 9 Stretch : `/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libiptc.so.0` is provided by `libiptc0` . Are you trying to upgrade from 7 Wheezy to 9 Stretch ?

Answer (score 0):

The problem was in missing files in /lib. I copied this files from other linux machine and create symlinks and now it is ok.